# jQuery - Reload page after following jump link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, reload

I'm creating a slideshow effect using hidden div's. Once a thumbnail is clicked, the corresponding div appears in a window and the other divs are hidden. However, I also need the page to reload. I attempted to use something like this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

However, this will reload the page without following the link (something like a href="#div02"). How do I get it to both follow the link and reload the page?

Comment: What does the reload accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to set up a video page. The problem I was having is that since all the video pages were on the same page, if one was playing when a user clicked a thumb to go to a new video, the old video would still be playing. Thus, by reloading the page, the page is reset with a new video. I found a workaround using show() and hide() but its a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is to modify the URL of the browser to reflect the current state of the DOM. Meaning, if a user clicked on a picture, the URL would be updated by appending a "#div02" and finally the user would be able to share this link with friends which will take them directly to that picture/state.

If that's what you want, your looking for Location Hash. To set:

```
window.location.hash = "#div02";
```

To get:

```
window.location.hash
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure this is what I was looking for. I'll try to re-explain it:

I'm setting up a video page. I've got a main window with overflow: hidden which shows the current movie and has the others hidden from view. To the right are thumbnails to jump to other videos (which bring them into view). However, to get the previous video to stop playing, I would ideally follow the jump link and reload the page. The problem is that it doesn't follow the link and simply refreshes the page.

Comment: If that still didn't make sense, let me know and I'll set up a demo page.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reload the page just remove the element that embeds the previous video.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra parameter (with random value) to to your current url. The browser will reload the page and then jumb to an anchor since your url has changed.

```
var randomString = Date.now();
window.location = "?something=" + randomString + "#div02";
```